# What does "shut off a flow of payments" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "**Qualcomm stopped paying Apple**"? If so, it should be the other way around.

I used this link: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shut-off?q=shut+off

The dispute actually started last year when Apple (AAPL, +1.39%) brought in Intel as an alternate supplier for wireless modem chips in about half of its iPhones and gave some information about Qualcomm’s business practices to regulators around the world. Apple complained that Qualcomm’s practice of charging royalties on a phone’s entire cost was excessive and should be disallowed since many of the patents involved are part of industry standards. **Qualcomm in turn shut off a flow of payments**—Apple described them as partial rebates on the royalties—leading Apple to sue Qualcomm and stop paying royalties. Qualcomm countersued and is trying to have iPhones with non-Qualcomm chips barred from being imported. But through it all, Apple has continued to pay for and buy wireless modem chips from Qualcomm for its newest iPhones.

Source: http://fortune.com/2017/10/31/Qualcomm-chips-apple-iphone-ditch/

Comment: What do you mean by "the other way around"? It was Qualcomm, not Apple, which ended the flow of payments.

Comment: So who paid who?

Comment: QualcomM was paying Apple, but not enough, according to Apple. So Qualcomm stopped paying Apple. There was no need for the writer to write: "shut off the flow of payments". It's just bad journalism. The writer could have just used: stopped paying Apple.

Comment: @Lambie Maybe the author was thinking "cash flow". Or just the fact they were regular payments.

Comment: Qualcomm had been returning to Apple, in the form of "rebates", some of the monies Apple had paid it in royalties. Qualcomm ended the rebates.  That is Apple's characterization of the Qualcomm payments ("Apple described them as partial rebates on the royalties").